# Dot-sourcing a script without executing it

Tags: powershell

Is it possible in Powershell to dot-source or re-use somehow script functions without it being executed? I'm trying to reuse the functions of a script, without executing the script itself.  I could factor out the functions into a functions only file but I'm trying to avoid doing that.

**Example dot-sourced file:**

```
function doA
{
    Write-Host "DoAMethod"
}

Write-Host "reuseme.ps1 main."
```

**Example consuming file:**

```
. ".\reuseme.ps1"

Write-Host "consume.ps1 main."
doA
```

**Execution results:**

```
reuseme.ps1 main.
consume.ps1 main.
DoAMethod
```

**Desired result:**

```
consume.ps1 main.
DoAMethod
```

Comment: Is modifying the original script (the one with the functions you want to import) an option? You could modify it to execute the rest of the code only if it is not being dot-sourced.

Comment: Nope - that was my first thought too.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid executing the file?

Comment: I want to reuse the "doA" function, but don't want the "Write-Host "reuseme.ps1 main."" behaviour.  I view the bit outside the function definitions as the 'main method'/entrypoint - I don't want the orchestration provided, just the behaviour from the functions.  I'm probably thinking a little to much in compiled code terms, rather than script terms.

Comment: Can't you just *not* put in the `Write-Host "reuseme.ps1 main"` into your function script?

Comment: Nope. Consider it auto-generated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You *have* to execute the function definitions to make them available. There is no way around it.

You could try throwing the PowerShell parser at the file and only executing function definitions and nothing else, but I guess the far easier approach would be to structure your reusable portions as modules or simply as scripts that don't do anything besides declaring functions.

For the record, a rough test script that would do exactly that:

```
$file = 'foo.ps1'

$tokens = @()
$errors = @()
$result = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($file, [ref]$tokens, [ref]$errors)

$tokens | %{$s=''; $braces = 0}{
    if ($_.TokenFlags -eq 'Keyword' -and $_.Kind -eq 'Function') {
        $inFunction = $true
    }
    if ($inFunction) { $s += $_.Text + ' ' }
    if ($_.TokenFlags -eq 'ParseModeInvariant' -and $_.Kind -eq 'LCurly') {
        $braces++
    }
    if ($_.TokenFlags -eq 'ParseModeInvariant' -and $_.Kind -eq 'RCurly') {
        $braces--
        if ($braces -eq 0) {
            $inFunction = $false;
        }
    }
    if (!$inFunction -and $s -ne '') {
        $s
        $s = ''
    }
} | iex
```

You will have problems if functions declared in the script reference script parameters (as the parameter block of the script isn't included). And there are probably a whole host of other problems that can occur that I cannot think of right now. My best advice is still to distinguish between reusable library scripts and scripts intended to be invoked.

Comment: I wouldn't go down the parsing route described, it looks like a can of worms. I was hoping I was missing a trick.

Answer (score 9):

After your function, the line **Write-Host "reuseme.ps1 main."** is known as "procedure code" (i.e., it is not within the function).  You can tell the script not to run this procedure code by wrapping it in an IF statement that evaluates **$MyInvocation.InvocationName -ne "."**

$MyInvocation.InvocationName looks at how the script was invoked and if you used the dot (.) to dot-source the script, it will ignore the procedure code.  If you run/invoke the script without the dot (.) then it will execute the procedure code.  Example below:

```
function doA
{
    Write-Host "DoAMethod"
}

If ($MyInvocation.InvocationName -ne ".")
{
    Write-Host "reuseme.ps1 main."
}
```

Thus, when you run the script normally, you will see the output. When you dot-source the script, you will NOT see the output; however, the function (but not the procedure code) will be added to the current scope.

Comment: Slick trick! This came in handy when writing Pester tests.  I used this to wrap my `main` method call allowing Pester to discover the functions in my script without running my `main` method.

Answer (score 4):

The best way to re-use code is to put your functions in a PowerShell module.  Simply create a file with all your functions and give it a `.psm1` extension.  You then import the module to make all your functions available.  For example, `reuseme.psm1`:

```
function doA
{
    Write-Host "DoAMethod"
}

Write-Host "reuseme.ps1 main."
```

Then, in whatever script you want to use your module of functions,

```
# If you're using PowerShell 2, you have to set $PSScriptRoot yourself:
# $PSScriptRoot = Split-Path -Parent -Path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
Import-Module -Name (Join-Path $PSScriptRoot reuseme.psm1 -Resolve)

doA
```

Comment: That executes "Write-Host "reuseme.ps1 main." before executing "doA" - which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way import functions from another file into the current scope without executing the file. Pretty useful when unit testing with Pester.

```
function Get-Functions($filePath)
{
    $script = Get-Command $filePath
    return $script.ScriptBlock.AST.FindAll({ $args[0] -is [Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst] }, $false)
}

Get-Functions ScriptPath.ps1 | Invoke-Expression
```

This works by invoking the Powershell parser directly, like in previous answers.

Answer was inspired by this thread:
[Is there a way to show all functions in a PowerShell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59993421/is-there-a-way-to-show-all-functions-in-a-powershell-script)

Comment: Perfect! Just remember to wrap that in a BeforeAll at the top of your Pester file.

Answer (score 1):

While looking a bit further for solutions for this issue, I came across a solution which is pretty much a followup to the hints in Aaron's answer. The intention is a bit different, but it can be used to achieve the same result.

This is what I found:
https://virtualengine.co.uk/2015/testing-private-functions-with-pester/

It needed it for some testing with Pester where I wanted to avoid changing the structure of the file before having written any tests for the logic.

It works quite well, and gives me the confidence to write some tests for the logic first, before refactoring the structure of the files so I no longer have to dot-source the functions.

```
Describe "SomeFunction" {
  # Import the ‘SomeFunction’ function into the current scope
  . (Get-FunctionDefinition –Path $scriptPath –Function SomeFunction)

  It "executes the function without executing the script" {
     SomeFunction | Should Be "fooBar"
 }
}
```

And the code for `Get-FunctionDefinition`

```
#Requires -Version 3

<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Retrieves a function's definition from a .ps1 file or ScriptBlock.
.DESCRIPTION
    Returns a function's source definition as a Powershell ScriptBlock from an
    external .ps1 file or existing ScriptBlock. This module is primarily
    intended to be used to test private/nested/internal functions with Pester
    by dot-sourcsing the internal function into Pester's scope.
.PARAMETER Function
    The source function's name to return as a [ScriptBlock].
.PARAMETER Path
    Path to a Powershell script file that contains the source function's
    definition.
.PARAMETER LiteralPath
    Literal path to a Powershell script file that contains the source
    function's definition.
.PARAMETER ScriptBlock
    A Powershell [ScriptBlock] that contains the function's definition.
.EXAMPLE
    If the following functions are defined in a file named 'PrivateFunction.ps1'

    function PublicFunction {
        param ()

        function PrivateFunction {
            param ()
            Write-Output 'InnerPrivate'
        }

        Write-Output (PrivateFunction)
    }

    The 'PrivateFunction' function can be tested with Pester by dot-sourcing
    the required function in the either the 'Describe', 'Context' or 'It'
    scopes.

    Describe "PrivateFunction" {
        It "tests private function" {
            ## Import the 'PrivateFunction' definition into the current scope.
            . (Get-FunctionDefinition -Path "$here\$sut" -Function PrivateFunction)
            PrivateFunction | Should BeExactly 'InnerPrivate'
        }
    }
.LINK
    https://virtualengine.co.uk/2015/testing-private-functions-with-pester/
#>
function Get-FunctionDefinition {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='Path')]
    [OutputType([System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock])]
    param (
        [Parameter(Position = 0,
          ValueFromPipeline = $true,
          ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
          ParameterSetName='Path')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [Alias('PSPath','FullName')]
        [System.String] $Path = (Get-Location -PSProvider FileSystem),

        [Parameter(Position = 0,
          ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true,
          ParameterSetName = 'LiteralPath')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.String] $LiteralPath,

        [Parameter(Position = 0,
          ValueFromPipeline = $true,
          ParameterSetName = 'ScriptBlock')]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock] $ScriptBlock,

        [Parameter(Mandatory = $true,
          Position =1,
          ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName = $true)]
        [Alias('Name')]
        [System.String] $Function        
    )

    begin {
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'Path') {
            $Path = $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path);
        }
        elseif ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'LiteralPath') {
            ## Set $Path reference to the literal path(s)
            $Path = $LiteralPath;          
        }
    } # end begin

    process {
        $errors = @();
        $tokens = @();
        if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ScriptBlock') {
            $ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput($ScriptBlock.ToString(), [ref] $tokens, [ref] $errors);
        } 
        else {
            $ast = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseFile($Path, [ref] $tokens, [ref] $errors);
        }

        [System.Boolean] $isFunctionFound = $false;
        $functions = $ast.FindAll({ $args[0] -is [System.Management.Automation.Language.FunctionDefinitionAst] }, $true);
        foreach ($f in $functions) {
            if ($f.Name -eq $Function) {
                Write-Output ([System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock]::Create($f.Extent.Text));
                $isFunctionFound = $true;
            }
        } # end foreach function

        if (-not $isFunctionFound) {
            if ($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'ScriptBlock') {
                $errorMessage = 'Function "{0}" not defined in script block.' -f $Function;
            }
            else {
               $errorMessage = 'Function "{0}" not defined in "{1}".' -f $Function, $Path;
            }
            Write-Error -Message $errorMessage;
        }
    } # end process
} #end function Get-Function
```